# Getting IP Address of the remote peer in Websocket API for Java EE 7

Tags: glassfish, websocket, ip-address

How can I get the IP address of the remote peer in Websocket API for Java Glassfish ?

Answer (score 2):

See [getRemoteAddr()](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/tyrus/blob/422e0d06889b42d5cd7c2c8123acd803945f821a/core/src/main/java/org/glassfish/tyrus/core/TyrusSession.java#L748)

You will need to cast your socket Session instance to a TyrusSession, which implements the standard JSR-356 Session interface.

You might need to upgrade Tyrus, as I am not sure if the version you have supports this method.  I am using [Tyrus 1.7](https://tyrus.java.net/) and it works fine for me.  Here is [how to upgrade](https://blogs.oracle.com/PavelBucek/entry/updating_tyrus_in_glassfish).

Answer (score 2):

Another method, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936440/accessing-httpsession-from-httpservletrequest-in-a-web-socket-socketendpoint/17994303#17994303) to another question, is to get the headers of the HandshakeRequest. The headers you are looking for are either of the following.

```
origin: [IP Address]
x-forwarded-for: [Possibly a separate IP]
```

Just for clarity, here's my setup, and how I discovered this:

- Wamp 2.5 on MyMachine:6060. This hosts a client HTML page.
- Wamp 2.5 on LabMachine:6060 (normal connections) and LabMachine:6443 (secure connections). This acts as a proxy.
- GlassFish 4.0 on MyMachine:8080 (normal) and MyMachine:8181 (SSL). This is the endpoint.

I connected to the client page via my own machine, the lab machine, and a colleague's machine. In every case, the origin header of the WebSocket request was

> http://MyMachine:6060

However, in each case the *x-forwarded-host* header was different, matching the IP addresses of the actual client.

Answer (score -2):

`WebSockets` are based on HTTP requests. Therefore you are probably extending an `HttpServlet` or a `WebSocketServlet` somewhere, so the usual way of getting the IP from the `HttpServletRequest` should work:

Example:

```
public class WebSocketsServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private final WebSocketApplication app = new WebSocketApplication();

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        WebSocketEngine.getEngine().register(
            config.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/context", app);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("IP: " + req.getRemoteAddr());
        super.doGet(req, resp);
    }

}
```

Comment: this is not using java ee 7 websocket api (see jsr 356); http://java.net/projects/websocket-spec/ ; http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=356