# How can I get a cookie value inside websocket end-point

Tags: cookies, websocket, java-ee-7

I'm using Websocket-API based on JavaEE 7, in my application.

I'm required to access the values set in cookies inside my websocket endpoint `[Annotated one : @ServerEndpoint ("/websocket") ]`. How would I do that?

`@onOpen()` method is there, which will be called automatically when a connection to this websocket endpoint is established. I want to access cookies values in there, inside this method.

I know how to do that in a servlet or JSP, but I'm new to Websockets.

Please help me doing this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Access to request parameters is done via the `@ServerEndpoint(configurator=MyConfigurator.class)` technique.

See [other answer on how to access the HttpSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936440/accessing-httpsession-from-httpservletrequest-in-a-web-socket-socketendpoint/17994303#17994303), as its techniques are very similar.

Comment: That's really wonderful. I can successfully get HttpSession using the way you've illustrated.
But my intention is to get the cookies, not HttpSession; I tried the same scenario, but failed to get it.


'this.httpCookie = (HttpSession) config.getUserProperties()
                .get(HttpCookie.class.getName());'

I don't know how to put this HttpCookie into EndPointConfig, thru modifyHandshake() method of the Configurator.
Help me doing this.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the original question

Comment: @gshauger this was really a duplicate question, hence the reference to the other answer on accessing the HttpSession (where Cookies are traditionally accessed from in JEE applications)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Thanks for the link to the other answer.  There is a wealth of information there.

Answer (score 10):

While Joakim's answer does provide a hint in the right direction I believe it does not fully answer the question, or at least can be complemented.

In order to retrieve the value of a cookie you must get the headers of the HandshakeRequest object, and look for the header named "cookie". Your modifyHandshake implementation will look something like:

```
public class MyEndpointConfigurator extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator {
    @Override
    public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig config, 
                                HandshakeRequest request, 
                                HandshakeResponse response)
    {
        Map<String,List<String>> headers = request.getHeaders();
        config.getUserProperties().put("cookie",headers.get("cookie"));
    }
}
```