# Websocket - httpSession returns null

Tags: session, tomcat, websocket, httpsession

I would like to make the connection between a websocket handshake \ session to a HttpSession object.

I've used the following handshake modification:

```
public class GetHttpSessionConfigurator extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator
{
@Override
public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig config, 
                            HandshakeRequest request, 
                            HandshakeResponse response)
{
    HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession)request.getHttpSession();
    config.getUserProperties().put(HttpSession.class.getName(),httpSession);
}
}
```

As mentioned in this post:
[Accessing HttpSession from HttpServletRequest in a Web Socket @ServerEndpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936440/accessing-httpsession-from-httpservletrequest-in-a-web-socket-socketendpoint)

Now,
For some reason on the hand shake, the (HttpSession)request.getHttpSession() returns null all the time.

here is my client side code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing websockets</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Start" onclick="start()" />
</div>
<div id="messages"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var webSocket = 
        new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/com-byteslounge-websockets/websocket');

    webSocket.onerror = function(event) {
        onError(event)
    };

    webSocket.onopen = function(event) {
        onOpen(event)
    };

    webSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
        onMessage(event)
    };

    function onMessage(event) {
        document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML 
            += '<br />' + event.data;
    }

    function onOpen(event) {
        document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML 
            = 'Connection established';
    }

    function onError(event) {
        alert(event.data);
    }

    function start() {
        webSocket.send('hello');
        return false;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas why no session is created ?
Thanks

Comment: I hope keeping the client side code in `Servlet` or `jsp` instead of plain html might help, since session object will be initiated in those cases. I haven't tried though.

Comment: I have this issue only if I access my web app through a reverse proxy (nginx). On direct access, getHttpSession does not return null. What is different when using nginx?

Comment: Found my issue: was mixing "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" in URLs. The http session id was not sent for the other host name I guess.

Answer (score 11):

This is intended behaviour, but I agree it might be confusing. From the HandshakeRequest.getHttpSession javadoc:

> ```
> /**
>  * Return a reference to the HttpSession that the web socket handshake that 
>  * started this conversation was part of, if the implementation
>  * is part of a Java EE web container.
>  *
>  * @return the http session or {@code null} if either the websocket
>  * implementation is not part of a Java EE web container, or there is
>  * no HttpSession associated with the opening handshake request.
>  */
> ```

Problem is, that HttpSession was not yet created for your client connection and WebSocket API implementation just asks whether there is something created and if not, it **does not create it**. What you need to do is call `httpServletRequest.getSession()` sometime **before** WebSocket impl filter is invoked (`doFilter(...)` is called).

This can be achieved for example by calling mentioned method in `ServletRequestListener#requestInitalized` or in different filter, etc..

Comment: How do you get the httpservletRequest object from the ServletRequestEvent pServletRequestEvent object passed to the requestInitalized method?

Answer (score 9):

Here is an impl for Pavel Bucek's Answer, after adding it, i got my session

```
import javax.servlet.ServletRequestEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@WebListener
public class RequestListener implements ServletRequestListener {

    @Override
    public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
        ((HttpServletRequest) sre.getServletRequest()).getSession();
    }

}
```

Comment: Since I usually disable Jar Scanning for a faster startup, I had to also add a listener to web.xml, e.g. `<listener><listener-class>path.to.RequestListener</listener-class></listener>` in order to register the `@WebListener` without relying on the annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [@pavel-bucek 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20288055/968244), I wrote a [simple `HttpSessionInitializerFilter` servlet filter](https://github.com/isapir/servlet-filter-utils/blob/master/README.md#httpsessioninitializerfilter).

Just download the jar from the "Releases" page and save it anywhere in the classpath, then add the following snippet to your web.xml descriptor (modify the url-pattern as needed):

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>HttpSessionInitializerFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>net.twentyonesolutions.servlet.filter.HttpSessionInitializerFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>HttpSessionInitializerFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

first: create a new class

```
import javax.servlet.ServletRequestEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@WebListener

public class RequestListener implements ServletRequestListener {

    @Override
    public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent servletRequestEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent servletRequestEvent) {
        ((HttpServletRequest)servletRequestEvent.getServletRequest()).getSession();
    }
}
```

and then add the "ServletComponentScan" annotation on the App main:

```
@SpringBootApplication

@ServletComponentScan

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```