# Accessing ServletContext and HttpSession in @OnMessage of a JSR-356 @ServerEndpoint

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, websocket, httpsession, java-websocket

I need to get the `ServletContext` from inside a `@ServerEndpoint` in order to find Spring `ApplicationContext` and lookup for a Bean.

For the moment my best approach is to bind that bean in the JNDI naming context and lookup it in the `Endpoint`. Any better solution is welcome.

I'm also looking for a reasonable way to sync servlet's `HttpSession` with websocket's `Session`.

Comment: I am also trying to access ServletContext from inside a websocket endpoint. Trying to do this in Tomcat.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22880055/jsr-356-websockets-with-tomcat-how-to-limit-connections-within-single-ip-addre/23025059#23025059

Comment: Do you have to lookup the bean?  Why can you not inject it?  It should be injectable if you use `configurator = org.springframework.web.socket.server.endpoint.SpringConfigurator.class` in your `@ServerEndpoint` annotation.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The servlet `HttpSession` is in JSR-356 available by [`HandshakeRequest#getHttpSession()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/HandshakeRequest.html#getHttpSession%28%29) which is in turn available when a handshake request is made right before [`@OnOpen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/OnOpen.html) of a [`@ServerEndpoint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpoint.html). The `ServletContext` is in turn just available via [`HttpSession#getServletContext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getServletContext%28%29). That's two birds with one stone.

In order to capture the handshake request, implement a [`ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html) and override the [`modifyHandshake()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html#modifyHandshake%28javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig,%20javax.websocket.server.HandshakeRequest,%20javax.websocket.HandshakeResponse%29) method. The `HandshakeRequest` is here available as method argument. You can put the `HttpSession` into [`EndpointConfig#getUserProperties()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/EndpointConfig.html#getUserProperties%28%29). The `EndpointConfig` is in turn available as method argument [`@OnOpen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/OnOpen.html).

Here's a kickoff example of the `ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator` implementation:

```
public class ServletAwareConfig extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator {

    @Override
    public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig config, HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response) {
        HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) request.getHttpSession();
        config.getUserProperties().put("httpSession", httpSession);
    }

}
```

Here's how you can use it, note the [`configurator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpoint.html#configurator%28%29) attribute of the `@ServerEndpoint`:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="/your_socket", configurator=ServletAwareConfig.class)
public class YourSocket {

    private EndpointConfig config;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session websocketSession, EndpointConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) config.getUserProperties().get("httpSession");
        ServletContext servletContext = httpSession.getServletContext();
        // ...
    }

}
```

As a design hint, it's the best to keep your `@ServerEndpoint` fully free of servlet API dependencies. You'd in the `modifyHandshake()` implementation better immediately extract exactly *that* information (usually a mutable Javabean) you need from the servlet session or context and put them in the user properties map instead. If you don't do that, then you should keep in mind that a websocket session can live longer than the HTTP session. So when you still carry around `HttpSession` into the endpoint, then you may run into `IllegalStateException` when you try to access it while it's being expired.

In case you happen to have CDI (and perhaps JSF) at hands, you may get inspiration from the source code of [OmniFaces `<o:socket>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/push/socket) (links are at very bottom of showcase).

#### See also:

- [Real time updates from database using JSF/Java EE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947790/real-time-updates-from-database-using-jsf-java-ee)
- [Notify only specific user(s) through WebSockets, when something is modified in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426674/notify-only-specific-users-through-websockets-when-something-is-modified-in-t)

Comment: Thanks for this explanation and especially for the hint to keep Endpoints free of servlet API dependencies.

Comment: Instead inject the servlet context as user property i inserted The spring context; it's not like to autowire the bean, but it works and solved my issue.

Comment: for websocket it seems like the code in Omniface example is using an HTTP request to increment the counter. What am I missing here , doesn't it defies the point?

Comment: @Ced: it just triggers the push.

Comment: If anyone is getting null while getting HttpSession, here is the solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240591/websocket-httpsession-returns-null

Comment: enforcing session for each request may not be acceptable in some situations (cookies disabled, users explicitly refusing any data storage). I've submitted a [PR to the API](https://github.com/jakartaee/websocket/pull/416) to add `getServletContext()` to `HandshakeRequest`: please give it thumbs-up :)

Answer (score 5):

Updated code for BalusC's answer, the onOpen method needs to be decorated with @OnOpen. Then there is no need anymore to extend the Endpoint class:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="/your_socket", configurator=ServletAwareConfig.class)
public class YourSocket {

    private EndpointConfig config;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session websocketSession, EndpointConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) config.getUserProperties().get("httpSession");
        ServletContext servletContext = httpSession.getServletContext();
        // ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried out BalusC's answer on Tomcat (Versions 7.0.56 and 8.0.14). On both containers, the modifyHandshake's request parameter does not contain a HttpSession (and thus no servletContext).
As I needed the servlet context only to access "global" variables (web-application global, that is), I just stored these variables in an ordinary static field of a holder class. This is inelegant, but it worked.

That ooks like a bug in this specific tomcat versions - has anyone out there also seen this?

Comment: No, it's not a bug. It indicates that a httpSession is simply not created. You could create it yourself beforehand. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240591/websocket-httpsession-returns-null for more info.

Comment: Thank you - this is a solution I didn't think of (I thought the Session was always created by the infrastructure). Alas, as I wanted to use this only for application global data, I still will stick with the hand crafted solution, as it works now.

Comment: (This shouldn't have been posted as an _answer_)  Behaviour is the same in Jetty.  As @Kalle points out; just use a `HttpFilter` or `ServletRequestListener` and call `request.getSession(true)`   -  shame there's no similar overload on `HandshakeRequest.getHttpSession()`

Answer (score 0):

Somtimes we can't get `session` with above `ServletAwareConfig` of BalusC, this is because that the session is still not created. since we are not seek for session but servletContext, in tomcat we can do as below:

```
public static class ServletAwareConfig extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator {

    @Override
    public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig config, HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response) {
        try {
            Field reqfld = request.getClass().getDeclaredField("request");
            reqfld.setAccessible(true);
            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) reqfld.get(request);
            ServletContext ctxt = req.getServletContext();
            Map<String, Object> up = config.getUserProperties();
            up.put("servletContext", ctxt);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        }
    }

}
```

if we want init session immediately, we can call request.getSession().

Ref: [Websocket - httpSession returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240591/websocket-httpsession-returns-null)