# How can I get real system file path from within a WebSocket Endpoint

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket, java-ee-7

While I am within a Servlet Context I can easily get the real system file path by calling on request.getServletContext().getRealPath(UPLOAD_PATH). Please friends how can I do the equivalent from within a WebSocket Endpoint in Java EE 7. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get path information from the [ServerEndpointConfig#getPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.html#getPath()). The only difference between the results of this method and `ServletContext#getRealPath()` is that this gives the relateive path; you could just prefix the results of that method with the root context name. To get the results, you need to implement `onOpen` (from the `javax.websocket.Endpoint` class)

```
//called when the client first negotiates the opening of the websocket connection
public void onOpen(Session session, ServerEndpointConfig config){

   String path = config.getPath();

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @kolossus for the responses, but unfortunately that didn't solve my problem. ServerEndpointConfig#getPath() return path for the deployed endpoint. But what i am looking is the real system path. Something that could look like /home/projects/java/web/projectname just as it is in ServletContext#getRealPath()

Comment: @Paullo - you could use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23405830/1530938) to get the servletcontext, and from there see if the path returned works for you

Comment: I dont think so, I have searched through the API but there's nothing like that. But I will any sample code if you thing it is posible