# How to get web content path with wildfly 9/websocket as it is done with request.getServletContext().getRealPath(UPLOAD_PATH)?

Tags: java, websocket, wildfly, java-websocket

I seen this topic: [How can I get real system file path from within a WebSocket Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967556/how-can-i-get-real-system-file-path-from-within-a-websocket-endpoint)

With the same problem. I tried  to use:

```
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session, ServerEndpointConfig config){
    contextPath = config.getPath();
}
```

But when I try to deploy wildly raise this error:

```
17:59:33,634 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 101) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: UT003012: Method public void fr.foo.server.BarEndPoint.onOpen(javax.websocket.Session,javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig) has invalid parameters at locations [1]
```

I would like to get this path into onMessage method to generate an image dynamically.

Thanks for your help,

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it:

```
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config){
    session.getUserProperties().put("contextPath", ((ServerEndpointConfig)config).getPath())
}
```