# How to logout a user if his account is deleted/disable from admin side?

Tags: jsp, servlets

If i am going to delete employee if employee is logged in after deleting or disable his/her account how he will automatically logout from his account

[image: 1]

How employee automatically logout after account deletion happen from  admin side

Comment: Remove/invalidate their session on the server side. Unless you have a web socket/polling/etc on the client side they won’t know they’ve been logged out until they make another request.

Comment: Unrelated but the image does not provide any useful information; it’s a picture of a table (with a… curious color palette).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *actively* logout the user, you'll need to send a push message which in turn basically triggers the submit of a hidden logout form. You can do this via a web socket. A kickoff example can be found in this answer: [Notify only specific user(s) through WebSockets, when something is modified in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426674/notify-only-specific-users-through-websockets-when-something-is-modified-in-t/32476664#32476664).

To *passively* logout the user, you'll need to implement a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which checks on every single request if the currently logged-in user is still valid. Here's a kickoff example assuming that you're using [homegrown user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274279/authentication-filter-and-servlet-for-login/13276996#13276996) (which is confirmed by [the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdpua.png) as visible in your deleted answer here):

```java
@WebFilter("/whatever_url_pattern_covering_your_restricted_pages/*")
public class YourLoginFilter extends HttpFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletRequest response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        YourUser user = (session == null) ? null : (YourUser) session.getAttribute("user");
        
        if (user == null) {
            // No logged-in user found, so redirect to login page.
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login");
        } else {
            // Logged-in user found, so validate it.
            if (yourUserService.isValid(user)) {
                // User is still valid, so continue request.
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
                // User is not valid anymore (e.g. deleted by admin), so block request.
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/blocked");
            }
        }
    }
}
```