# Websocket getting remote IP on connect

Tags: java, websocket

Can I get remote IP address inside `@OnOpen` method of `@ServletEndpoint` class?
I tried follow this [Accessing HttpSession from HttpServletRequest in a Web Socket @SocketEndpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936440/accessing-httpsession-from-httpservletrequest-in-a-web-socket-socketendpoint) but as in [Websocket - httpSession returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240591/websocket-httpsession-returns-null) it doesn't work.

Anyway I only need clients IP address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSR-356 Websocket specification does not expose client IP address.

You may try one of the 2 hacks descibed in this response:
[JSR-356 WebSockets with Tomcat - How to limit connections within single IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22880055/jsr-356-websockets-with-tomcat-how-to-limit-connections-within-single-ip-addre)

Comment: OK I used the httpSession and ServletRequestListener and it works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Added: Works for Jetty implementation and it's not a common solution. Thanks to Benjamin !

Don't know if you still need it. I myself directly get the IP from the socket Session.

```
@OnOpen
public void onWebSocketConnect(Session session) {
    System.Out.println(session.getUserProperties().get("javax.websocket.endpoint.remoteAddress"))
}
```

Then I get /127.0.0.1:57045

Comment: The `javax.websocket.endpoint.remoteAddress` property is not part of the JSR-356 (see http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=356). I suspect this is something specific to Jetty's websocket implementation. For example, I tried on WildFly 8.2, which uses Undertow, and the `session.getUserProperties()` returns a Map with no predefined values... So this solution is not portable and may not work on all websocket implementations.

Comment: @Benjamin  I agree. I was using Jetty implementation but found no answer at that time. Then I tried most of its API to find a solution for me and post the answer here. I haven't try any other implementation.

Comment: For Tomcat there is a workaround with reflection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32629586/166524

Comment: @AereXu this does not work if Jetty is behind NGINX.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the client will be some Javascript code in a web page delivered by your web application.

Have the client first fetch a servlet, that calls req.getRemoteAddr() and so on
Servlet returns this data.
Javascript then can send the data as @PathParam to the @ServerEndpoint.