# Set (Websocket) ServerEndpoint's configurator without annoatations

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, websocket

Insprired by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936440/accessing-httpsession-from-httpservletrequest-in-a-web-socket-socketendpoint) I'm trying to do this:

```
@ServerEndpoint(... configurator = GetHttpSessionConfigurator.class)
```

without the @ServerEndpoint annotation but with this code:

```
ServerEndpointConfig endpointConfig = ServerEndpointConfig.Builder.create(MyHandler.class, uri).build();
javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer.addEndpoint(endpointConfig);
```

Since I couldn't find any "setConfigurator" methods, I checked the sources of ServerEndpointConfig and I found that the Configuration (..tor) is loaded by

```
 ServiceLoader.load(Configurator.class)
```

so, I created a meta-inf\services\javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig$Configurator file and added a single line to point to my GetHttpSessionConfigurator (as defined in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936440/accessing-httpsession-from-httpservletrequest-in-a-web-socket-socketendpoint)) class. The file is loaded (I checked that with Process Monitor) but Tomcat's DefaultServerEndpointConfig is used.

Does anyone has an idea what's wrong with this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before your `.build()`  you can put in a `.configurator(new YourEndPointConfigurator())`

So for your code you can do something like:

```
ServerEndpointConfig endpointConfig = ServerEndpointConfig.Builder
  .create(MyHandler.class, uri)
  .configurator(new ChatServerEndPointConfigurator(new GetHttpSessionConfigurator())
  .build();
```

More information can be found in [`ServerEndpointConfig.Builder` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Builder.html).