# Strange behavior with Websockets, HTTPSessions and Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, tomcat, websocket, httpsession

I am seeing very odd behavior with Chrome and websockets, with respect to HTTPSessions.

It seems that in Chrome each tabs has its own HTTPSession (unlike Firefox where they all share the same HTTPSession).  But, when to connect to a WebSocket from JavaScript in Chrome inside a webpage, the HTTPSession that is uses seems to be random, or at least not always the one from the current page.

The behavior I'm seeing on the server (tomcat) is that sometimes the HTTPSession is null (or an old session the server doesn't know anything about), or the HTTPSession from another tab.

This seems to be some kind of bug in Chrome, Firefox never has any issues, and always gives the HTTPSession from the page.

This is related to this post on getting an HTTPSession from a WebSocket in Tomcat.

Can anyone confirm this, or know any workarounds to get the HTTPSession from a WebSocket?

[Accessing HttpSession from HttpServletRequest in a Web Socket @ServerEndpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936440/accessing-httpsession-from-httpservletrequest-in-a-web-socket-socketendpoint)