# The httpsession which i get from modifyHandshake is not the correct session,why?

Tags: java, servlets, websocket

First,I set attribute in servlet before websocket.

I'm sure the attribute is not null and print it on console.

```
session.setAttribute("user",request.getParameter("name"));
```

Then I establish websocket from HTML5 and get httpsession in modifyHandshake. But I get null.

```
public class GetHttpSessionConfigurator extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator
{
    @Override
    public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig config, 
                                HandshakeRequest request, 
                                HandshakeResponse response)
    {
        HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession)request.getHttpSession();
            config.getUserProperties().put(HttpSession.class.getName(),httpSession);
        System.out.println("username:"+httpSession.getAttribute("user"));
    }
}
```

It print 'null' on console.

Why?

Comment: This might be a helpful read for you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936440/accessing-httpsession-from-httpservletrequest-in-a-web-socket-socketendpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936440/accessing-httpsession-from-httpservletrequest-in-a-web-socket-socketendpoint)