# Accessing HttpServletRequest properties within a WebSocket @ServerEndpoint

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, websocket, java-websocket

I need to access the `HttpServletRequest` properties to get the *javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate* which contains the `X509Certificate` array of certificates for TLS requests.

From a JAX-RS `ContainerRequestFilter` I can easily extract this from the `ContainerRequestContext.getProperty(String property)` method, but I can't find a way to get it from the WebSocket `Session` nor the `HandshakeRequest`, from which I can access the `HttpSession` instance but not the `HttpServletRequest` one.

Note: this is not a duplicate of [Accessing HttpSession from HttpServletRequest in a Web Socket @ServerEndpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936440) since I need accesso to the `HttpServletRequest` (or equivalent to extract the TLS certificates), not `HttpSession`.

Since WebSocket is a superset of HTTP, I guess it should be possibile and hope the Java team had thought of a way to access the servlet properties, but I really couldn't find one. Anyone knows if this is possible at all?

Answer (score 6):

Without hacking:

1. Create servlet filter on URL pattern matching websocket handshake request.
2. In filter, get request attribute of interest and put it in session before continuing chain.
3. Finally get it from the session which is in turn just available via handshake request.

With hacking:

1. Use reflection to find `ServletRequest` field in handshake request instance.
2. Get its `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate` attribute.

   In other words:

   ```
   public class ServletAwareConfigurator extends Configurator {

       @Override
       public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig config, HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response) {
           ServletRequest servletRequest = getField(request, ServletRequest.class);
           X509Certificate[] certificates = (X509Certificate[]) servletRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
           // ...
       }

       private static <I, F> F getField(I instance, Class<F> fieldType) {
           try {
               for (Class<?> type = instance.getClass(); type != Object.class; type = type.getSuperclass()) {
                   for (Field field : type.getDeclaredFields()) {
                       if (fieldType.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
                           field.setAccessible(true);
                           return (F) field.get(instance);
                       }
                   }
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               // Handle?
           }

           return null;
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you @BalusC, this could work. I'd rather like not to use `HttpSession`, if possibile. I wonder if WebSocket actually use `HttpServeltRequest` and just doesn't expose it in its API or doesn't use it at all…

Comment: It's implementation specific. That's exactly why "Without hacking" :)

Comment: You're right! I'm on WildFly/Undertow btw. If the WebSocket JSR exposes `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession` in the `HandshakeRequest` API, I really don't see why it doesn't expose `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`…

Comment: WS handshake is not per definition triggered by a HTTP servlet request. So it cannot be exposed in API (otherwise, extreme tight coupling and unreusable API). Basically, it should have exposed kind of `getAttribute()`/`getAttributeMap()` orso.

Comment: Right again. I mean just that since WebSocket are accessibile via TLS (wss://) the API should expose a path to get info about the secure connection, such as the client X509 certificates (as in `HttpServletRequest`, i.e. `X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) request.getProperty("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate")`).

Comment: Post an issue at WS spec guys requesting a new method which accomplishes at least that task: https://java.net/jira/browse/WEBSOCKET_SPEC

Comment: It'd been easier if you post the requirement in Servlet API perspective, not in JAX-RS API perspective as WebSockets does not use JAX-RS API under the covers, but just Servlet API. I.e. `HttpServletRequest.getAttribute(...)`.