# WebSocket server get client certificate onOpen

Tags: java, ssl, websocket, wildfly, x509certificate

I have a simple `ServerEndpoint` running on WildFly 10, which is configured as `wss` with mutual TLS, so client certificate required. I have no problems in connecting to endpoint, so the mutual authentication is correctly done, but I can't access client certificate in `onOpen` method. I am trying to do it using `getUserPrincipal()`, I'm always getting `null`.

I need to get client certificate for authorization purposes.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Principal;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.websocket.EndpointConfig;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/test", configurator = GetHttpSessionConfigurator.class)
public class TestWebSocketEndPoint {

    private Session wsSession;
    private HttpSession httpSession;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config){
        this.wsSession = session;
        this.httpSession = (HttpSession) config.getUserProperties().get(HttpSession.class.getName());
        Principal userPrincipal = session.getUserPrincipal();
        System.out.println(session.getId() + " has opened a connection"); 
        try {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Connection Established");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * When a user sends a message to the server, this method will intercept the message
     * and allow us to react to it. For now the message is read as a String.
     */
    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session){
        System.out.println("Message from " + session.getId() + ": " + message);
        try {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * The user closes the connection.
     * 
     * Note: you can't send messages to the client from this method
     */
    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session){
        System.out.println("Session " +session.getId()+" has ended");
    }
}
```

GetHttpSessionConfigurator:

```
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.websocket.HandshakeResponse;
import javax.websocket.server.HandshakeRequest;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig;

public class GetHttpSessionConfigurator extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator {
    @Override
    public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig config, 
                                HandshakeRequest request, 
                                HandshakeResponse response)
    {
        HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession)request.getHttpSession();
        Map<String, List<String>> map = request.getParameterMap();
        Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
        config.getUserProperties().put(HttpSession.class.getName(),httpSession);
    }
}
```

RequestListener:

```
import java.security.Principal;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.servlet.ServletRequestEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@WebListener
public class RequestListener implements ServletRequestListener {

    public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
        ((HttpServletRequest) sre.getServletRequest()).getSession();
        Principal p = ((HttpServletRequest) sre.getServletRequest()).getUserPrincipal();

        boolean secure = ((HttpServletRequest) sre.getServletRequest()).isSecure();
        String authType = ((HttpServletRequest) sre.getServletRequest()).getAuthType();

        X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) ((HttpServletRequest) sre.getServletRequest()).getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
    }

}
```

The websocket client is a standalone application using TooTallNate/java-websocket and connecting securely:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl;

public class TestClient {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(TestClient.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        WebSocketImpl.DEBUG = true;

        WSRAClient wsRaClient = new WSRAClient(new URI("wss://localhost:8443/TestWebSocket-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test"));

        String keystoreFile = "keystore.p12";
        String keystorePassword = "keystore";

        String truststoreFile = "truststore.jks";
        String truststorePassword = "truststore";


        try {
            SSLContext ssl = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");

            log.info("Configuring SSL keystore");
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()); 
            KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            log.debug("Loading keystore");
            store.load(new FileInputStream(keystoreFile), keystorePassword.toCharArray());
            log.debug("Number of keystore certificates: " + store.size());
            Enumeration<String> enumeration = store.aliases();
            while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                String alias = enumeration.nextElement();
                log.debug("alias name: " + alias);
                Certificate certificate = store.getCertificate(alias);
                log.debug(certificate.toString());
            }
            kmf.init(store, keystorePassword.toCharArray());
            KeyManager[] keyManagers = new KeyManager[1];
            keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();

            log.info("Configuring SSL truststore");
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            log.debug("Loading truststore");
            truststore.load(new FileInputStream(truststoreFile), truststorePassword.toCharArray());
            log.debug("Number of truststore certificates: " + truststore.size());
            enumeration = truststore.aliases();
            while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                String alias = (String)enumeration.nextElement();
                log.debug("alias name: " + alias);
                Certificate certificate = truststore.getCertificate(alias);
                log.debug(certificate.toString());
            }
            tmf.init(truststore);
            TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();

            ssl.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());

            SSLSocketFactory factory = ssl.getSocketFactory();// (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

            wsRaClient.setSocket(factory.createSocket());

            wsRaClient.connectBlocking();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            while ( true ) {
                String line = reader.readLine();
                if(line.equals("close")) {
                    wsRaClient.close();
                } else {
                    wsRaClient.send(line);
                }
            }

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error(e);
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error(e);
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error(e);
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error(e);
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error(e);
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error(e);
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error(e);
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error(e);
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

See : [Accessing HttpServletRequest properties within a WebSocket @ServerEndpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184382/accessing-httpservletrequest-properties-within-a-websocket-serverendpoint)

> 1. Create servlet filter on URL pattern matching websocket handshake request.
> 2. In filter, get request attribute of interest and put it in session before continuing chain.
> 3. Finally get it from the session which is in turn just available via handshake request