# Extract Client Certificate information when using mTLS and WSS

Tags: java, tomcat, x509, wss

I have a java application running in Tomcat. I added https listener on port 8443 as described here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.x/reference/pdf/spring-boot-reference.pdf (9.3.13. Enable Multiple Connectors with Tomcat)

I additionally configured the listener to challenge clients to present certificates (2-way-TLS / mutual TLS) and have a truststore with trusted entries. All of this works and I can see the whole TLS-Handshake in the logs, along with the client certificate presented.

I have a WebSocket server endpoint (`@javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint`) which does get called when a client is connecting via "wss://....." after the secure tls tunnel is established, the `@OnOpen` method is called and it has javax.websocket.Session object. So the http(s) upgrade to ws works.

***My Question:*** After the TLS-Handshake is performed (triggered by WSS: ws over https in my case), I need to extract client certificate (X509) information (subject / issuer etc..) and have it available in the @OnOpen method. I was searching for some Interceptors or another way to access and extract certificate data and make it available **after** the upgrade to ws is done. Is there any way to access `HttpServletRequest` from the `@OnOpen` web socket handling method? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

After looking furthermore I was able to do it.

Step 1: Tap into modifyHandshake(...) method and obtain `ServletRequest` object, `HttpSession` will not do the job. Credits go to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184382/accessing-httpservletrequest-properties-within-a-websocket-serverendpoint/36187427#36187427).

```
package example.com;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.websocket.HandshakeResponse;
import javax.websocket.server.HandshakeRequest;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig;    

public class InjectAttributesIntoWebSocketConfigurator extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator {

  @Override
  public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig config, HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response) {
    ServletRequest servletRequest = getField(request, ServletRequest.class);
    X509Certificate[] certificates = (X509Certificate[]) servletRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
    // certificates[0] is client certificate
    // do null/error/empty array handling here
    config.getUserProperties().put("clientcert", certificates[0]);
  }

  private static <I, F> F getField(I instance, Class<F> fieldType) {
    try {
      for (Class<?> type = instance.getClass(); type != Object.class; type = type.getSuperclass()) {
        for (Field field : type.getDeclaredFields()) {
          if (fieldType.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            return (F) field.get(instance);
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // Handle?
    }
     return null;
  }
}
```

Step 2: Configure WS to use the configurator above and read whatever parameters from the `Session` object (you have to had previously added those in the modifyHandshake() metod).

```
@ServerEndpoint(
        value = "/some/endpoint/here",
        configurator = InjectAttributesIntoWebSocketConfigurator.class
)
```

Step 3: Done :). Now, the WS endpoint has client certificate with which the TLS (2-way TLS in my case) underlying HTTPS connection was established.