# Remove endpoint from ServerContainer inside WebListener

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, dependency-injection, jira

In my JIRA plug-in I have created a WebListener which add a websocket endpoint to the SeverContainer.

The problem is, when I make changes to my plugin and upload it in JIRA, the new code is not executed.

This is because the endpoint is not being deployed again. I get the following exception: Multiple Endpoints may not be deployed to the same path

My weblistener:

```
@WebListener
public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyListener.class);

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        final ServerContainer serverContainer = (ServerContainer) servletContextEvent.getServletContext()
                .getAttribute("javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer");
        try {
            serverContainer.addEndpoint(MyWebsocket.class); //Generates exception when the plug-in is updated
        } catch (DeploymentException e) {
            LOG.error("Error adding endpoint to the servercontainer: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        LOG.error("CONTEXT DESTROYED!");
    }
}
```

My websocket:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket/{myPathParam}")
public class MyWebsocket {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyWebsocket.class);

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, @PathParam("myPathParam") String myPathParam) {
        LOG.error("OnOpen");
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, @PathParam("myPathParam") String myPathParam) {
        LOG.error("OnClose");
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session, @PathParam("myPathParam") String myPathParam) {
        LOG.error("OnMessage: " + message);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to remove the endpoint from the servercontainer, so it will be deployed again?

Comment: I believe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936440/accessing-httpsession-from-httpservletrequest-in-a-web-socket-serverendpoint

Answer (score 0):

In the specification, I did not find any way to deactivate a websocket. The same applies for `ServletContextListeners`. They can only be added. So you need a workaround.

I suggest, that you do not replace the `MyEndpoint.class`, but make it a proxy that will call an implementation. Thus, the endpoint will not be required to re-register and the new proxy class calls the new code, when it is deployed.

So, you can just safely ignore the `DeploymentException` in your code, because you change the `MyWebsocket.class` as follows:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket/{myPathParam}")
public class MyWebsocket {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyWebsocket.class);

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, @PathParam("myPathParam") String myPathParam) {
        LOG.error("OnOpen");
        WebSocketImpl impl = ImplementationFactory.get(MyWebsocket.class);
        impl.onOpen(session, myPathParam);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, @PathParam("myPathParam") String myPathParam) {
        LOG.error("OnClose");
        WebSocketImpl impl = ImplementationFactory.get(MyWebsocket.class);
        impl.onClose(session, myPathParam);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session, @PathParam("myPathParam") String myPathParam) {
        LOG.error("OnMessage: " + message);
        WebSocketImpl impl = ImplementationFactory.get(MyWebsocket.class);
        impl.onMessage(message, session, myPathParam);
    }
}
```

I understand, that this will not really answer your question, but it is a solution how to work around the missing remove options.

One problem is there with this workaround: It will fix your interface, you cannot add parameters in a new version of the plugin.

To enable this, you add another websocket by adding another context listener (`V7` has been choosen at random):

```
@WebListener
public class MyListener_V7 implements ServletContextListener {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyListener_V7.class);

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    final ServerContainer serverContainer = (ServerContainer) servletContextEvent.getServletContext()
            .getAttribute("javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer");
    try {
        serverContainer.addEndpoint(MyWebsocket_V7.class); //Generates exception when the plug-in is updated
    } catch (DeploymentException e) {
        LOG.error("Error adding endpoint to the servercontainer: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    LOG.error("CONTEXT DESTROYED!");
}
}

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket_V7/{myPathParam}")
public class MyWebsocket_V7 {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyWebsocket.class);
```

This will litter the JIRA instance with endpoints until a restart happens. But if you mix the two suggestions, you will only add a new endpoint every once in a while.