# How to send message to the @ServerEndpoint from .class

Tags: java, sockets, websocket, glassfish, endpoint

I don't know how to send a message to the @ServerEndpoint. I want to send a message from different project to the project which contains @ServerEndpoint.
@ServerEndpoint code below...

```
@ServerEndpoint("/posluzitelj")
@Stateless
public class Posluzitelj {
    static Queue<Session> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    public static void send(String message) {
       
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message) {

    }

    @OnOpen
    public void openConnection(Session session) {
        queue.add(session);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void closedConnection(Session session) {
        queue.remove(session);
    }

    @OnError
    public void error(Session session, Throwable t) {
        queue.remove(session);
    }
    
}
```

So, I wanna trigger onMessage function via another project class. How can I do that?
Also, I do not want to use javascript! I wanna make communication with java language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send a message through web socket to a connected user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42804923/how-to-send-a-message-through-web-socket-to-a-connected-user)

Comment: @MykolaMurza, unfortunately, no. I want to send a message to the socket endpoint. I know how to do that with js, for example: WebSocket ws=new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8084/application_1/posluzitelj");

Comment: Problem is solved with @ClientEndpoint annotation.
Link: [@ClientEndpoint class implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452903/javax-websocket-client-simple-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved with @ClientEndpoint annotation. Link: [ServerEndpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452903/javax-websocket-client-simple-example)